# Symfony4 - How to "setParameter"

Tags: php, symfony, service, parameters

I'm trying to use the

```
container->setParameter('abc','ABC')
```

to save a value in my "services.yaml", but everywhere I put that line it says i'm not allowed to do it when it's compiled.

How can I use it to store a value for the next runs ?

Comment: why are you trying to dynamically change your container setup? what is the exact error message? can we see code?

Comment: I am conversing with an api that need to make a loooooot of requests to find a path, which will whange every month. Instead of going recusively through the tree of all folder with the api, I would like to store the value of the current valid folder. Then if it's not it will only  do the recursive search once and store the new valid ID again.

Comment: As it is just ONE id, i'm not sure a database would be a good idea..

Comment: the service container where you want to save your parameter is not for this, its not to be modified after being compiled. I think symfony comes with a cache service you can use for this purpose (https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-cache-component)

Comment: ok i will try to see with the cache, bus as there is a "setParameter" available i though that it was here for a reason

Comment: its there for use while the container is being built/compiled https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a parameter inside the container before it is compiled. It's designed to store configuration parameters. For example you can access `kernel.project_dir` parameter (and many others of this kind).

You can modify and add theses parameters in different places:

- In your [Kernel.php class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/kernel.html)
- In any [CompilerPass class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html)
- In a [Bundle extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html)

In any of theses cases, it happens before the container is compile (and cached for optimization purpose).

---

If you need some kind of parameter bag, you can use the `attributes` parameter of the [Request](http://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) (that have the advantage to be regenerate for subrequests in your code). You can also simply define your own parameter bag service.